# why am i unable to scroll? ubuntu 18.04

Tags: command-line, 18.04, server, scrolling

I have tried everything it seems. Ive reinstalled recently and now unable to scroll.

Im using ubuntu 18.04 server

Shift + pageup/down does nothing. Ctrl + shift + up/down key does nothing. Ctrl + A then escape does nothing.

Information i have found is outdated. I was able to scroll the other day. Now i am unable.

I dont know what has changed.

Any advice?

Comment: If you're accessing your server directly you cannot scroll because it is using a TTY and not a Terminal.  However, if you access your server from a client using ssh you should be able to scroll just fine in the terminal window you have open.  And if you can't scroll remotely make sure that the scrolling is enabled in the Terminal Preferences.

Answer (score 2):

Here are two things you can do to try and restore scrolling:

**1 — Reset the Terminal**

0. Open the Terminal
1. Type: `reset`

The terminal will appear empty for a couple of seconds, then it will come back and be ready for commands.

If that doesn't work ...

**2 — Verify the Preferences**

0. Open the Terminal (if not already open)
1. Open the Preferences window
2. Verify the "Scrolling" details in your profile:

   [image: Terminal - Scrolling Preferences]

   I generally have this set to a ridiculous number like 10,000, but confirm that the number is greater than 50.

If neither of these work, the terminal may be stuck in "cursor addressing mode", and that would be a more complicated fix. Hopefully one of these two will resolve your issue.

Comment: I am on ubuntu server , dont think i can access the gui. I will try both suggestions nonetheless . Thanks for your input